# WinError 267 The directory name is invalid

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I tried this code in jupyter notebook, and this error occured.

```
Error : [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'plantdisease/PlantVillage/Pepper__bell___Bacterial_spot/0022d6b7-d47c-4ee2-ae9a-392a53f48647___JR_B.Spot 8964.JPG/'
```

I'm using python 3.6 in anaconda environment, I tried running this code but it showed error. I can't figure out what the problem is.The file location actually exists at the given location, still it shows invalid.

```
image_list, label_list = [], []
try:
    print("[INFO] Loading images ...")
    root_dir = listdir(directory_root)
    for directory in root_dir :
        # remove .DS_Store from list
        if directory == ".DS_Store" :
            root_dir.remove(directory)

    for plant_folder in root_dir :
        plant_disease_folder_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}")

        for disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list :
            # remove .DS_Store from list
            if disease_folder == ".DS_Store" :
                plant_disease_folder_list.remove(disease_folder)

        for plant_disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list:
            print(f"[INFO] Processing {plant_disease_folder} ...")
            plant_disease_image_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/")

            for single_plant_disease_image in plant_disease_image_list :
                if single_plant_disease_image == ".DS_Store" :
                    plant_disease_image_list.remove(single_plant_disease_image)

            for image in plant_disease_image_list[:200]:
                image_directory = f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/{image}"
                if image_directory.endswith(".jpg") == True or image_directory.endswith(".JPG") == True:
                    image_list.append(convert_image_to_array(image_directory))
                    label_list.append(plant_disease_folder)
    print("[INFO] Image loading completed")  
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error : {e}")
```

**[SOLVED]** the problem was in loading the root director make sure you're root directory is loaded, if your root directory is plantDiseases then, keep it similar, son't get deep in the directory.

Comment: Please don't put "Solved" in the title. Instead, post an answer (yes you can answer your own question), then click the checkmark to accept it, which basically marks the issue as solved.

Comment: BTW I've only skimmed the code, but it seems like catching Exception then printing it makes errors harder to diagnose since you lose the traceback.

Comment: I agree with @wjandrea, don’t catch the exceptions just to print them.

Answer (score 1):

Your path is invalid because it is not a directory. It is a file

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the path to this
directory_root = 'D:\Coding files\Plant disease/x/'

x is the folder in which PlantVillage dataset is saved in

[image]

[image: Path of PlantVillage Dataset]